# LoadFileUrl and LoadHtmlString not loading local document resources

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, wkwebview

Basically using HybridWebView which uses WKWebview I'm loading a downloading an html file with a bunch of css files that are stored in the app documents directory.
Example

var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C9D9BB56-79B6-4990-A599-18C6AD928A22/Documents

I can load the html just fine using LoadFileUrl or LoadHTMLString, the issue is that the referenced css and js does not load into the webview

This is my file url

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C9D9BB56-79B6-4990-A599-18C6AD928A22/Documents/Courses/2d7d0a7d-145a-41d0-9abf-685a2b5dfc3c/Online_Placement_Test_no_timer_pack/YKZOP4NACH3EPJNTG6M4T2BQDI/Unit_4_5/995/Unit.html
```

Base Url

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C9D9BB56-79B6-4990-A599-18C6AD928A22/Documents/Courses/2d7d0a7d-145a-41d0-9abf-685a2b5dfc3c/Online_Placement_Test_no_timer_pack/YKZOP4NACH3EPJNTG6M4T2BQDI/Unit_4_5/995/
```

And this is an example of a path to a resource that doesn't load grabbed from the network inspector in Safari.

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C9D9BB56-79B6-4990-A599-18C6AD928A22/Documents/Courses/2d7d0a7d-145a-41d0-9abf-685a2b5dfc3c/Online_Placement_Test_no_timer_pack/YKZOP4NACH3EPJNTG6M4T2BQDI/Unit_4_5/995/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I've even set

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
    <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
    <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>    
    </dict>
```

in info.plist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain the doc dir via `NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetUrl`.

#### Example loading "WebSite" from App's document directory

```
var docsDir = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetUrl(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomain.User, null, true, out var error);
var data = NSUrl.FromFilename(Path.Combine(docsDir.Path, "WebSite", "index.html"));
var content = NSUrl.FromFilename(Path.Combine(docsDir.Path, "WebSite"));
webView.LoadFileUrl(data, content);
```

#### Example loading "WebSite" from bundled resources:

```
var bundlePath = NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath;
var data = NSUrl.FromFilename(Path.Combine(bundlePath, "WebSite", "index.html"));
var content = NSUrl.FromFilename(Path.Combine(bundlePath, "WebSite"));
webView.LoadFileUrl(data, content);
```

#### Using an downloaded Azure sample website

Note: Downloaded to a `WebSite` subdir within  `NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory`

```
├── css
│   └── site.css
├── fonts
│   └── segoeuil.ttf
├── img
│   ├── cloneWhite.svg
│   ├── deployWhite.svg
│   ├── lightbulbWhite.svg
│   ├── stackWhite.svg
│   ├── successCloudNew.svg
│   └── tweetThis.svg
└── index.html
```

#### Local Output:

[image]

Comment: Sir you are a champion.

Made a few changes.

`var docsDir = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetUrl(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomain.User, null, true, out var error);
                var data = NSUrl.FromFilename(Path.Combine(docsDir.Path, Element.iOSPath));`

               ` var content = NSUrl.FromFilename(Path.Combine(docsDir.Path, "Courses"));`

Where I went wrong was with the readAccessUrl. I only needed to include up to the Courses directory.

Answer (score 0):

**Loading a locally stored website or html-File from the filesystem's App's caches directory using WebKit WKWebView in Objective-C in iOS13**

Note the very important webView.configuration.preferences setting allowFileAccessFromFileURLs!!

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *downloadDir = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docsDir, @"www"];

NSURL* downloadDirUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:downloadDir];
NSLog(@"DIR  '%@'", downloadDirUrl);
NSURL* indexHtmlUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@", downloadDir, @"/index.html?param=val"]];
NSLog(@"HTML '%@'", indexHtmlUrl);

WKWebView* webView = ...;
[webView.configuration.preferences setValue:@YES forKey:@"allowFileAccessFromFileURLs"];
[webView loadFileURL:indexHtmlUrl allowingReadAccessToURL:downloadDirUrl];
```